# iframe loading in middle of page, instead of top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm embedding wetransfer through iframe into a website, but the problem I have is when the page loads, it automatically jumps past the header section of the site, instead of having the new page load at the top of the page.

How can I stop this from happening? I tried using jquery scrollto, but doesn't make any difference.

https://jsfiddle.net/dbruning22/c0s6mhkv/1/

HTML

```
<header>
  Some Header information and navigation
</header>
<body>
  <iframe src="https://www.wetransfer.com/" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

CSS

```
header { 
  background: green;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

header height is 600px so iframe is placed right behind.

If you want iframe to cover the page from the top you should set

```
iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0s6mhkv/4/)

If you want to place iframe right behind header, just remove

```
height: 600px;
```

[fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/c0s6mhkv/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
header { 
  background: green;
  height: 600px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The green header is 600 px high because of your CSS. Adjust the `height:` value as needed.

Also, `<header>` is a regular page content tag and therefore should be placed inside `<body>`, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

First:  put header tag inside body tag. Not outside.

```html
<body>
<header>
  Some Header information and navigation
</header>
  <iframe src="https://www.wetransfer.com/" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

Second:
Remove 600px height from header css.

Profit :)

Comment: The header outside the body tag was a typo, but wouldn't make a difference with how the iframe in generated. The height of the header is set to the height of the user's screen and in there is a large background image, logos and some animation. I just added the fixed height of 600px to illustrate the point that it jumps to the middle of the screen when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

use following code :

```
<header>
  Some Header information and navigation
</header>
<body>
<div>
  <iframe src="#" width="100%" height="400" id="iFrm"></iframe>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var documentHeight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );


    var iframeHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("iFrm").getAttribute("height"))


    document.getElementById("iFrm").style.marginTop = (documentHeight - iframeHeight) / 2;
</script>
```

Its working fine for me. Hopefully works for you

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you want it to be like this but try it out

```
<header>
  Some Header information and navigation
</header>
<body>
  <iframe class="test" src="https://www.wetransfer.com/" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

css:

```
header { 
  background: green;
  height: 600px;
}
.test {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

But you could use angularjs modal_dialogue to make a pop up window which would display your information from an url.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  My iframe html has:

```
  <body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="admin-pages" id="top-of-page">
      etc...
    </div>
  </body>
```

And javascript:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#top-of-page").scroll();
  etc...
```

Takes the iframe to the #top-of-page when the page loads.